# Strategy for advertizing poker stackexchange

Tags: discussion

It seems like we need more users to really get this beta going.  How do you guys want to promote this site?  The easy solution is to post on popular poker forums like 2+2.  Any other sites we should post on?  Any other ideas for generating traffic/users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good ideas, in other way StackExchange can buy payed ads on other poker sites to poker stackexchange and community can do banners for this advertising campaign.

Answer (score 3):

Grinderschool.com does a weekly poker podcast. At some point in the future I would be open to doing a segment in which I interview about the Poker Stackexchange site. Things are too hectic to fit it in for the next few weeks, but we can sort out the details between now and then if there its someone here who would want to be interviewed.

Comment: I would do that.  I'm a computer programmer that was a stackoverflow guy before the other sites started popping up.  Best Question and Answer software on the net.

Comment: Who would we interview?  Top users?  A SE community activist?

Comment: I would think a top user would make the most sense. I was thinking you or Toby would be the most likely candidate, but I'm not ruling out k-to-the-z. We have some time to figure it out, if we want to go that way.

Answer (score 1):

I have a friend who founded a startup that specializes in Word Of Mouth marketing, amongst other friends who are directly employed in marketing companies.

SE sites are mostly community/volunteer driven from what I understand so growing the user base would exponentially increase our traffic if we can instill an ethos of promoting through the users.

Maybe some "Guerilla" style marketing, using fly posting, sponsored swag poker tournaments, even a community curated idea for a short film that promotes poker.se across well known video sharing sites.

Just sounding off ideas.

---

(edit: Poker.SE could even get into sponsoring people for tournaments to increase exposure).

(edit 29/01/2015: I've been recently been reminded of ["Community Ads"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/), some good examples [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/lets-make-more-community-ads), & thought we could do something like this for Poker.SE).

Comment: Sponsored swag tournaments sounds fantastic.  I wonder if we could get stickers that we could leave in casino poker rooms?

Comment: Stickers are what I had in mind. Leave them outside local casinos here in London, that kind of thing. Some sponsored events would perhaps be even cheaper than traditional advertising routes, and would target the influential people socially as well.

Comment: Just thought, if we do get tournaments going for PokerStack, we could offer a special badge and maybe some rep points for winning.

Answer (score 1):

You reach a large audience when you get the commentators of live streams like EPT live stream from Pokerstars to talk about poker.SE.

It's not that hard for german audience, because we got our own stream and those guys like to talk about new stuff in the poker scene + there's a public chat that everyone is reading too.

So to next EPT in Vienna I'd suggest everyone to watch those streams and post over twitter + email or chat to your commentators.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be cool if you guys got an SE dev on your side to develop an in question / in answer hand / table simulator similar to what Chess.SE has for game layouts. Would make the site very unique.

Comment: That would be cool, but it's hard enough to get people to even post all the relevant data in a hand history.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd be surprised how many people would visit this site if you did a sponsored freeroll.

$10 a week for an exclusive Stack Exchange freeroll tournament wouldn't break the bank and could potentially bring in 5000+ users if Pokerstars allows that many in a private tournament.

PKR used to release a freeroll code a few hours before a freeroll tournament. I imagine at first it would be good to release the code from the start of the week/month until activity picked up.

A few freely placed links on other freeroll listing sites could also drive users this way.

It wouldn't have to be seen as "endorsing gambling" if it was done with community spirit, and nobody would be overly competitive about $10.

It could be further developed into a community league if the membership of this site became valuable enough to SE.

On the topic, what kind of users would it bring in? My guess is 60% annoying, 20% non-engaging, 20% perfect target users.

Just a speculative idea.